# Get ItemID Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId outlook mac os add-in

Tags: angularjs, macos, outlook, ms-office, add-in

First post here ;)

I need some help, I'm working on an add-in for appointment and I can't get the itemID of the current item. I'm working on mac os outllok dekstop client (the last version), I try to get it with :

```js
var itemId = Office.context.mailbox.item.itemId;
  if (itemId === null || itemId == undefined) {
    Office.context.mailbox.item.saveAsync(function (result) {
      itemId = result.value;
    });
}
```

but from what I understand, it doesn't work on outlook mac os.

I really need this to make api calls and use extensions, with older versions of outlook office for mac os it worked.

Thank you in advance and have a great day.

Comment: Hi, did you find any workaround for this? Experiencing the same issue with Outlook 16.46 for Mac + "new design" turned on.

Answer (score 1):

From what I found on the doc:

> The `itemId` property is not available in compose mode. If an item identifier is required, the `saveAsync` method can be used to save the item to the store, which will return the item identifier in the asyncResult.value parameter in the callback function.

So if you want to get the property we must **save it first**.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/outlook/office.appointmentread?view=outlook-js-1.5&preserve-view=true#itemId